# How do HTML event handler attributes work?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events, web-component

just got question about how does HTML works.

As far as I know, attribute of HTMLElement is only 'string | null'

but as we know, on HTML

```
<div onclick="sayHi()" />
```

works.

I'm wondering, how does 'sayHi' string gets map into actual function object.

and in advance, for web components, can we pass functions to web-component attributes? not using global object as proxy?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes#event_handler_attributes

Answer (score -2, accepted):

That MDN link is wrong (IMHO) when it says those type of *inline* events should not be used.

https://javascript.info/introduction-browser-events has a better and more complete explanation.

`this.onclick = (evt) => { }` is perfectly valid when used in the `connectedCallback` of a Web Component,
because the outside world should not have anything to do with a Web Components internals, and `this.addEventListenerer("click",(evt=>{  });` (which does the same, but allows for multiple events) is just longer,
and *implies* using a not required `removeEventListener` because listeners on DOM nodes (the Web Component) are *garbage collected*, thus automatically removed.

Note `<my-component onclick=" ">` is a different notation for the same `this.onclick` handler. If you really need to add a click handler in HTML you *might* want to do `<my-component onclick="this.getRootNode().METHOD()">` to call a **method** on your Web Component.

`this.onclick = ()=>{ }` will override your HTML defined handler.

### NOTE

thanks for reminding me, Kaiido

- `<my-component onclick="function()">` runs in **global *scope***
- and `this.onclick` runs in **component *scope***

Comment: That's just plain wrong. The event content attribute (the one you set in the markup) is nothing like the `.onevent` IDL attribute.

Comment: this is SO, its all about code. Alas https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/59f4t7s2/ logs _**"Kaiido is wrong"**_ in my browser

Comment: Nope, sorry, they just don't behave the same: https://jsfiddle.net/hv3uwn61/ vs https://jsfiddle.net/hv3uwn61/1/ Please, read about the subject matters you talk about.

Comment: Yes, they run in different **scope** but they are the same handler

Comment: They just do different stuff. The question is how does the content attribute converts the DOMString to a function. Your answer is saying it's the same as the IDL attribute. This is plain wrong. And no, it doesn't "run in global scope", it runs in very bug-prone `with document { with target{ } }` scope. That's why **everyone** says these should be avoided. And `this.onclick` runs in whatever scope the function it's been set to has been declared to.

Comment: Again, ``this.onclick`` **overwrites** the ``onclick=".."``  It is the **same handler**. In your second example, explain why there is only **one** line in the console, and which code-line logged that line... its poteytoes potaatoes between JS nerds.

Comment: The question is exactly about how poteytoes differs from potatoes. So yes, setting the IDL attribute will overwrite the content one, and vice-versa but that's not the question. The question once again is *how is the DOMString converted to a function.* The IDL attribute just don't do that conversion and that's why no-one is arguing against its use.

Comment: See OPs other questions, he is a beginner JS developer. Educate him how to hold the hammer, not how the iron is forged.

Comment: Nah, just answer the question at hand. But actually, no need, this question already had an answer elsewhere.